# Find contiguous subsequences such that cube of the sum of numbers is at most y

Tags: algorithm, sequence, dynamic-programming

I am given a sequence of numbers A[1..n] and a fixed number y. The sequence may contain negative values.
My algorithm should be able to decide whether the sequence can be partitioned into contiguous subsequences such that cube of the sum of numbers in each subsequence is at most y. Here's my initial answer:

[image]

I believe this algorithm is reasonable, but I'd like to hear your opinions before moving forward with memoization. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sum of cubes, or cube of sums? Your question says one, but your picture says the other.

Comment: It's also hard to understand your picture. What does the notation i<=j<=n{...} mean? Does it mean "there exists j with i<=j<=n such that?"

Comment: Sorry to make confusion. I need "cube of sums". I fixed the picture accordingly.

Comment: @Anonymous - I forgot to explicitly say that I defined the sequence as A[1..n].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is correct, but it's O(n^2) rather than O(n).

To improve it, you can use this:

```
minsum([]) = 0
minsum(xs + [x]) = minsum(xs) + x if minsum(xs)^3 > y
                 = min(minsum(xs) + x, x) otherwise.
```

This finds a partition of the list such that each part has sum-cubed <= y, except for the last which just has the sum as small as possible. The function returns this minimum sum of the last part of the partition.

This formulation of the problem gives you an iterative solution, which you can consider a form of dynamic programming, since the solution at step n depends on the solution at step n-1.

```
def exists_partition(xs, y):
   m = 0
   for x in xs:
       m = m + x if m**3 > y else min(m + x, x)
   return m**3 <= y
```

Comment: What is xs? What is m**3?

Answer (score 1):

Given your description, you obviously don't need to repeatedly calculate cubes.

Instead, you can calculate the 3rd root of `y` **once**, and then pass it to your function.

Here is the recursive way of doing it (although dynamic programming might prove a lot more efficient). The solution below assumes that the input sequence contains only integer values, but it can be easily converted to take a sequence of rational values:

```
bool Partition(int values[],int numOfValues,int root3_y)
{
    for (int i=1; i<numOfValues; i++)
    {
        if (Partition(values,i,root3_y) && Partition(values+i,numOfValues-i,root3_y))
            return true;
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<numOfValues; i++)
        sum += values[i];
    return sum <= root3_y;
}
```